# A bug of GitHub Pages?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I have a blog(http://hueidou.github.io/) on GitHub Pages which has a images directory named "images", works well before.

Then, I create a new Repository named "images" and create the gh-pages branch which public to http://hueidou.github.io/images/. It also works well self, but It makes the link of my blog images all broken, like http://hueidou.github.io/images/rss.png.

Then, I have delete the Repository named "images", but, the problem still.

How to resolve it?

---11 Apr 2014 00:32:27 GMT---

GitHub Support had rebuild my site, here is the response.

> Sorry for the trouble you're having. As you've discovered, naming a Project Page repository and a User Page subfolder with the same name will cause a conflict on our servers. It's best to not use the same names for those.
>
> I've rebuilt your User Page site, so the images subdirectory should be working again.

Answer (score 1):

Visiting the site right now, I can see your RSS image in the footer, so your link to `http://hueidou.github.io/images/rss.png` does work.

Here's proof:

[image: rss]

However, you're seeing the 404 at `http://hueidou.github.io/images/` because [that directory](https://github.com/hueidou/hueidou.github.io/tree/master/images) doesn't have an index file, which is expected behavior for directly hitting any directory without an index file on GitHub pages.